# What is the difference between "-Dmaven.test.skip.exec" vs "-Dmaven.test.skip=true" and "-DskipTests"?

Tags: maven

I am not sure what the difference between the maven directives `-Dmaven.test.skip.exec` and `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` `-DskipTests` are. Both seem to suppress the testing cycle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685100/how-can-i-get-maven-release-plugin-to-skip-my-tests/14779004#14779004

Comment: Not really a dupe of that question, which is more "I tried all these and they don't work" ... :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

"`maven.test.skip.exec=true`" the tests get compiled, but not executed.

"`maven.test.skip=true`" doesn't compile or execute the tests.

"`-DskipTests`" is the [same](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/gump-general/201009.mbox/%3CAANLkTiktv2f8JwSFhbRwwbR5V0zCr1uRWc-rxmnF04Bu@mail.gmail.com%3E) as "`maven.test.skip.exec=true`"

Answer (score 20):

The [system property](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` will do the following:

> because maven.test.skip disables both running the tests and compiling
>   the tests.

The system property `-Dmaven.test.skip.exec` is deprecated where you should use `-DskipTests=true`

> Set this to "true" to skip running tests, but still compile them.

Answer (score 4):

Please look at the reference :
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html

Extract :

> Skipping Tests
>
> To skip running the tests for a particular project, set the skipTests
>   property to true.
>
> ```
> <project>
>   [...]
>   <build>
>     <plugins>
>       <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>2.18.1</version>
>         <configuration>
>           <skipTests>true</skipTests>
>         </configuration>
>       </plugin>
>     </plugins>
>   </build>
>   [...]
> </project>
> ```
>
> You can also skip the tests via the command line by executing the
>   following command:
>
> ```
> mvn install -DskipTests
> ```
>
> If you absolutely must, you can also use the maven.test.skip property
>   to skip compiling the tests. maven.test.skip is honored by Surefire,
>   Failsafe and the Compiler Plugin.
>
> ```
> mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
> ```