# What's the difference between -DskipTests and -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Tags: java, maven, hive

I was trying to build hive-0.13.

When using `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`, it will not build the test jars but it will check test dependency.

When using `-DskipTests`, it will not build the test jars and also not check test dependency.

What's the difference between `-DskipTests` and `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

[Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html):

`-DskipTests` compiles the tests, but skips running them

`-Dmaven.test.skip=true` skips compiling the tests **and** does not run them

Also this one might be important

> maven.test.skip is honored by Surefire, Failsafe and the Compiler
>   Plugin

Comment: Thanks, I also found this here: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html

Comment: Stanley, in your comment, the correct url is http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html

Answer (score 6):

There is a third, related option described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21933970/3169948

> "maven.test.skip.exec=true" the tests get compiled, but not executed.

So the complete set of test options for Maven would be:

- `-DskipTests` ==> the tests get compiled, but not executed.
- `-Dmaven.test.skip.exec=true` ==> the tests get compiled, but not executed (exactly the same as `-DskipTests`).
- `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` ==> doesn't compile or execute the tests.

Comment: The first two have the same effect, correct?  In other words, "skips running" == "not executed", right?  Does that also mean that both set the exact same properties etc., so are they really completely interchangeable?