# What are all of the Maven Command Line Options?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I'm looking for the list of options for Maven 2.2 but cannot find it. If someone knows the location please post it. Thank you.

I found the following but I don't know enough of Maven to know which are and are not in 2.2.
Version [Maven 3.3.3 CLI Options Reference](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-embedder/cli.html)

2021-08-09
**Updated for 3.8.1**

https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-embedder/cli.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996802/list-all-of-the-possible-goals-in-maven-2

Comment: Please upgrade to Maven3 cause [Maven 2 is EoL](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html)

Comment: Note: The answer has been updated to reflect version 3.6.3 from the prior 3.1.0.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Found this page today.
[Maven CLI Options Reference](https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-embedder/cli.html).

[image]

Text version to make it easy to copy/paste
Maven CLI Options Reference

Options >> Description

```
-am,--also-make >>  If project list is specified, also build projects required by the list
-amd,--also-make-dependents >>  If project list is specified, also build projects that depend on projects on the list
-B,--batch-mode >>  Run in non-interactive (batch) mode (disables output color)
-b,--builder    >>  The id of the build strategy to use
-C,--strict-checksums   >>  Fail the build if checksums don't match
-c,--lax-checksums      >>  Warn if checksums don't match
-cpu,--check-plugin-updates >>  Ineffective, only kept for backward compatibility
-D,--define     >>  Define a system property
-e,--errors     >>  Produce execution error messages
-emp,--encrypt-master-password  >>  Encrypt master security password
-ep,--encrypt-password  >>  Encrypt server password
-f,--file       >>  Force the use of an alternate POM file (or directory with pom.xml)
-fae,--fail-at-end  >>  Only fail the build afterwards; allow all non-impacted builds to continue
-ff,--fail-fast     >>  Stop at first failure in reactorized builds
-fn,--fail-never    >>  NEVER fail the build, regardless of project result
-gs,--global-settings   >>  Alternate path for the global settings file
-gt,--global-toolchains >>  Alternate path for the global toolchains file
-h,--help       >>  Display help information
-l,--log-file   >>  Log file where all build output will go (disables output color)
-llr,--legacy-local-repository  >>  Use Maven 2 Legacy Local Repository behaviour, ie no use of _remote.repositories. Can also be activated by using -Dmaven.legacyLocalRepo=true
-N,--non-recursive      >>  Do not recurse into sub-projects
-npr,--no-plugin-registry   >>  Ineffective, only kept for backward compatibility
-npu,--no-plugin-updates    >>  Ineffective, only kept for backward compatibility
-nsu,--no-snapshot-updates  >>  Suppress SNAPSHOT updates
-ntp,--no-transfer-progress >>  Do not display transfer progress when downloading or uploading
-o,--offline    >>  Work offline
-P,--activate-profiles  >>  Comma-delimited list of profiles to activate
-pl,--projects  >>  Comma-delimited list of specified reactor projects to build instead of all projects. A project can be specified by [groupId]:artifactId or by its relative path
-q,--quiet      >>  Quiet output - only show errors
-rf,--resume-from   >>  Resume reactor from specified project
-s,--settings       >>  Alternate path for the user settings file
-t,--toolchains     >>  Alternate path for the user toolchains file
-T,--threads        >>  Thread count, for instance 2.0C where C is core multiplied
-U,--update-snapshots   >>  Forces a check for missing releases and updated snapshots on remote repositories
-up,--update-plugins    >>  Ineffective, only kept for backward compatibility
-v,--version        >>  Display version information
-V,--show-version   >>  Display version information WITHOUT stopping build
-X,--debug      >>  Produce execution debug output
```

If you want to skip tests you can add the following to the command line.

```
-DskipTests
```

**compiles** the tests, but **skips running them**

```
-Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

**skips compiling** the tests and does **not run them**

Source [maven clean install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25639474/4226541)

Comment: Updated some content: Thanks to @Gustavo Passini, from version 3.1.0 to 3.6.3

Comment: may I suggest the URL https://maven.apache.org/ref/3-LATEST/maven-embedder/cli.html

Comment: Why are the CLI options only listed under Maven Embedder? I'm not using Maven Embedder.

Comment: The version-abstract URL that leads to the _current_ version, whatever it is, is: [`https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-embedder/cli.html`](https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-embedder/cli.html) (if you follow the link, the `current` part will turn into the actual current version number). /cc @myrdd

Answer (score 25):

If you have added the maven home path to the "PATH" environment variable, you can type in a terminal / cmd

```
mvn --help
```

If not, first add the maven bin path to the "PATH" variable:

Windows:

```
Go to System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment variables
```

and there add the maven bin directory path at the end of the PATH variable.

Unix/Linux:

```
export PATH=/your_path/apache-maven-VERSION/bin:$PATH
```

Warning: Add the maven path to the PATH environment variable, don't replace the actual content of the PATH variable

Take a look to:  https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: Great, but the existence of the --help option should have been mentioned in the Getting Started guide.