# Please explain this maven command - mvn -q -U clean install

Tags: maven

I am using cucumber framework for Automation Testing. For generating mvn reports, we use the following command

```
mvn -q -U clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=D:\\m2_local_repository\\..m2\\repository -DCucumber.options="--tags @*test_case_name*"
```

what is the purpose of `-q` and `-U`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553068/what-are-all-of-the-maven-command-line-options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-q` - Quiet output - only show errors

`-U` -  Forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories

Source : [Maven CLI reference](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html)