# Does -DskipTests implicitly call -Dmaven.test.skip?

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-plugin

I want to read maven `skipTests` property. Does `-DskipTests` and `-DskipIT` implicitly call `-Dmaven.test.skip` ?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639336/whats-the-difference-between-dskiptests-and-dmaven-test-skip-true

Answer (score 2):

-DskipTests compiles the tests, but skips running them while -Dmaven.test.skip = true skips compiling them all together (and skips running them as well)