# Maven-release-plugin to skip compiling and running tests setup in pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

Using maven-release-plugin, I have tried all possible ways I could (on command line as well), to `skip compiling` my tests but have not been successful so far. I want to do skip through pom. This is how my pom.xml looks

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <arguments>-Dmaven.test.skip</arguments>
            <goals>deploy</goals>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I have tried solutions from this post:
[How can I get maven-release-plugin to skip my tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685100/how-can-i-get-maven-release-plugin-to-skip-my-tests) but couldn't get it to work.

Tried surefire http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skip
but no luck.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.4</version>
  <configuration>
       <skip>true</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please help to fix my pom.xml using maven-release-plugin preferably.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this can only be done on the command line by setting

```
-Darguments="-Dmaven.test.skip=true -DskipTests"
```

Comment: is the -DskipTests option a must?

Comment: `maven.test.skip=true` skips _compiling_ the tests, `skipTests` skips _running_ the tests.

Comment: @MarcelStör No, maven.test.skip also skips running the tests: "*Set this to "true" to bypass unit tests entirely. Its use is NOT RECOMMENDED, especially if you enable it using the "maven.test.skip" property, because maven.test.skip disables both running the tests and compiling the tests. Consider using the skipTests parameter instead.*"

Comment: @blackbuild, thanks, makes a lot more sense that way. Sorry, my memory didn't serve me right on this one.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to figure out how to solve this without the maven-release-plugin. Compilation of the test-classes is done by the `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:testCompile`, while the execution is done by `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:test`.
So it is possible, but maybe the real question is: why  do you want this? Isn't this a workaround for the real cause?

Comment: I have some dependency issue in my tests which is failing the build, I wanted to get around that for a while to test some code changes that I have done. I am totally new to maven, the project I am working on has this pom with the test config so I thought of skipping it.

Comment: Why didn't you have used branches in your version control to get around things like this done? Apart from what Rober already mentioned.