# Maven Release Build Skip test case is fails - Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I am facing issue with Jenkins build using maven release build. The reason is for test case is failing. I am trying to skip the test cases but, its failing.

Screen shot of my Jenkins setting:-

[image]

Log :-

```
    ationTest): org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContext cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
  testReadNotCancelled(uk.com.xxx.yyy.sdp.bizservice.user.domain.dao.UserDaoIntegrationTest): org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContext cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
  testReadNotCancelledNullReturn(uk.com.xxx.yyy.sdp.bizservice.user.domain.dao.UserDaoIntegrationTest): org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContext cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
  testSaveUserPasswordReset(uk.com.xxx.yyy.sdp.bizservice.user.domain.dao.UserDaoIntegrationTest): org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContext cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
  testSaveUserPasswordChange(uk.com.xxx.yyy.sdp.bizservice.user.domain.dao.UserDaoIntegrationTest): org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContext cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

    Tests run: 232, Failures: 1, Errors: 135, Skipped: 3

    [ERROR] There are test failures.
```

Is there anything I am missing, please suggest.
Any advice would be helpful. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter is [**`-DskipTests=true`**](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#skip-test). You didn't provide a value...

Comment: Thanks Slav, I have tried this option with -Darguments='-DskipTests=true' . But its not working.

Comment: ... Where did you come up with `-Darguments`?? Put the line from my answer, in whole and as is, into your two "goals and options" fields.

Comment: Still its not working @Slav. I have used this commond -Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform -DskipTests=true

Comment: You do not need to provide a value, "-DskipTests" is equivalent to "-DskipTests=true". "-Darguments" is necessary as it is a forked process. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8685252/99231

Answer (score 4):

The command line you are (were ?) looking for is :

```
release:prepare release:perform "-Darguments=-DskipTests=true" (compile tests, non execution)
```

or

```
release:prepare release:perform "-Darguments=-Dmaven.test.skip=true" (do not even compile tests)
```

This plugin forks Maven (at least to run the tests), so you have to use

```
"-Darguments=-DskipTests=true -Dproperty1=value -Dproperty2=anothervalue"
```

to pass arguments to the forked process.

Comment: very important, but subtle, detail folks, `"-Darguments=` is necessary, thx Olivier!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
--batch-mode  -DskipTests -Darguments=-DskipTests  release:prepare
```