# Maven Release Plugin with multi module, is looking for test jars

Tags: java, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I have a relatively complex multi module java project

```
|PARENT
|pom.xml
|-submodule1
|-pom.xml
|--api
|--pom.xml
|--impl
|--pom.xml
|--model
|--pom.xml
|-submodule2
|...
```

and now I want my jenkins to create a release with

```
release:prepare -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true" --batch-mode -Dtag=$RELEASE_VERSION  -DreleaseVersion=$RELEASE_VERSION -DdevelopmentVersion=$DEVELOPE_VERSION
```

and then perform with

```
release:perform -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dmaven.test.skip=true" --batch-mode -Dtag=$RELEASE_VERSION  -DreleaseVersion=$RELEASE_VERSION -DdevelopmentVersion=$DEVELOPE_VERSION
```

Now the problem is that i have a submodule which contains integration tests and functional tests like restassured tests. Maven release plugin is looking  for

```
Failed to execute goal on project project-workflow: 
  Could not resolve dependencies for project 
  com.project.service:service-workflow:jar:1.0.2: 
  Could not find artifact com.project.service:service-service:service-client:jar:tests:1.0.2
  in public (http://ournexus.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public)
```

The maven declaration in workflow module is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>sevice-valuation-client</artifactId>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Do I need to deploy those testsources to nexus or can i somehow skip this kind of dependency ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685100/how-can-i-get-maven-release-plugin-to-skip-my-tests

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was that `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` doesn't compile testsources therefore the jar simply didn't existed once I removed it the process worked flawlessly